# retrieve value from a select query

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to retrieve a value from a mysql table to use it in another query but I keep getting an error because on the second query the value is not passed.

```
var id_customer='';
con1.query("SELECT id FROM utenze WHERE email='"+data.object.customer_email+"'", function (err, result, fields) {
    if(err) throw err;
    id_customer= result[0].id;
    console.log(id_customer);  //here id_customer has the correct value
});
console.log(id_customer); //here id_customer is empty
con2.query("SELECT ruolo FROM ruolo WHERE id_user="+id_customer, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
```

The second query will fail because id_customer remains empty.

`data.object.email` is correctly populated and the first query runs fine and returns a value.
What am i doing wrong? Is it related to how I retrieve the value from the first query?

EDIT: by further debugging tests result[0].id is returning the correct value

Answer (score 0):

The first query will only return the id of utenze because you wrote select id from utenze , and not select * . so maybe  replace **id_customer= result[0].id by  id_customer= result[0]**

Comment: this is not going to solve the issue. Query will always return an array with just one element